# Sklearn Pipeline persistance with custom class not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, deployment, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using sklearn pipeline in my code and saving the pipeline object to deploy in the another envinorment. I have one custom class to drop the features. I am saving the model successfully but when I am using the pipeline object in another envirorment which has same version of sklearn, it is throwing an error. The pipeline is working fine when I did not include my custom class **DropFeatures**. Below is the code

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.externals import joblib
# Load the Iris dataset
df = pd.read_csv('Iris.csv')
label = 'Species'
labels = df[label]
df.drop(['Species'],axis=1,inplace=True)
# Set up a pipeline with a feature selection preprocessor that
# selects the top 2 features to use.
# The pipeline then uses a RandomForestClassifier to train the model.
class DropFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, features_to_drop=None):
        self.features = features_to_drop

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
    # encode labels
        if len(self.features) != 0:
            X = X.copy()
            X = X.drop(self.features, axis=1)
            return X
        return X


pipeline = Pipeline([
      ('drop_features', DropFeatures(['Id'])),
      ('feature_selection', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1)),
      ('classification', RandomForestClassifier())
    ])


pipeline.fit(df, labels)
print(pipeline.predict(query))
# Export the classifier to a file
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'model.joblib')
```

When I am using the **model.joblib** in another environment, I am getting an error. Below is the code to load the model and error in the image

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('model1.joblib')
print(model)
```

Error stack trace:[image: Error stack trace image]